# closing one window in qt and opening another in python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to close one screen and open another, but i keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainMenu' object has no attribute 'show'
```

The code is:

```
class Something: 

    def Something(self):
        self.retranslateUi(Login)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ExitButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), Login.close)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.LoginButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.get_value_from_user)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Login)
        Login.setTabOrder(self.LoginButton, self.UsernameEdit)
        Login.setTabOrder(self.UsernameEdit, self.PasswordEdit)
        Login.setTabOrder(self.PasswordEdit, self.ExitButton)


    def get_value_from_user(self):
        Correct_details = False
        while Correct_details==False:
            inputusername=self.UsernameEdit.text()
            inputpassword=self.PasswordEdit.text()
            cur.execute("SELECT password FROM tblStaff WHERE username='"+inputusername+"'")
            password=str(cur.fetchone())
            password=password[2:-3]
            cur.execute("SELECT firstname FROM tblStaff WHERE username='"+inputusername+"'")
            FirstName=str(cur.fetchone())
            FirstName=FirstName[2:-3]
            cur.execute("SELECT surname FROM tblStaff WHERE username='"+inputusername+"'")
            Surname=str(cur.fetchone())
            Surname=Surname[2:-3]
            if str(password) == str(inputpassword):
                self.msgBox1 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information,'Successful', "Succesfully Logged in")
                self.msgBox1.show()
                Correct_details = True
            else:
                self.msgBox2 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, 'Warning', "The Username or Password you have entered is incorrect - Please try again (CASE SENSITIVE)")
                self.msgBox2.show()
                self.UsernameEdit.clear()
                self.PasswordEdit.clear()
                break

            self.msgBox1 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information,'Successful', "Succesfully Logged in")
            self.msgBox1.show()
            time.sleep(3)
            self.run_mainmenu()

    def run_mainmenu(self):
        self.mainmenu= Ui_MainMenu()
        Login.close()
        self.mainmenu.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, Login):
        Login.setWindowTitle(_translate("Login", "Login", None))
        self.UsernameEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Login", "Username", None))
        self.PasswordEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Login", "Password", None))
        self.ExitButton.setText(_translate("Login", "Exit", None))
        self.LoginButton.setText(_translate("Login", "Login", None))
        self.LoginTitle.setText(_translate("Login", "Login", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Login", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">STATION</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">JEWELLERS </span></p></body></html>", None))

class Ui_MainMenu(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainMenu):
        MainMenu.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainMenu"))
        MainMenu.resize(401, 223)
        MainMenu.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(79, 129, 189);"))
        MainMenu.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        self.MainMenuTitle = QtGui.QLabel(MainMenu)
        self.MainMenuTitle.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 0, 271, 76))
        self.MainMenuTitle.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 10))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Palatino Linotype"))
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.MainMenuTitle.setFont(font)
        self.MainMenuTitle.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainMenuTitle"))
        self.logo = QtGui.QLabel(MainMenu)
        self.logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 81, 51))
        self.logo.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);"))
        self.logo.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("logo"))
        self.LogOutButton = QtGui.QPushButton(MainMenu)
        self.LogOutButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 10, 51, 20))
        self.LogOutButton.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.LogOutButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("LogOutButton"))
        self.Changepassword = QtGui.QPushButton(MainMenu)
        self.Changepassword.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Changepassword.setFont(font)
        self.Changepassword.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.Changepassword.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Changepassword"))
        self.Staff = QtGui.QPushButton(MainMenu)
        self.Staff.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 90, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Staff.setFont(font)
        self.Staff.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.Staff.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Staff"))
        self.Customer = QtGui.QPushButton(MainMenu)
        self.Customer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 90, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Customer.setFont(font)
        self.Customer.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.Customer.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Customer"))
        self.Repair = QtGui.QPushButton(MainMenu)
        self.Repair.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 150, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Repair.setFont(font)
        self.Repair.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.Repair.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Repair"))
        self.sale = QtGui.QPushButton(MainMenu)
        self.sale.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 150, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.sale.setFont(font)
        self.sale.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.sale.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("sale"))

        self.retranslateUi(MainMenu)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainMenu)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainMenu):
        MainMenu.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainMenu", "MainMenu", None))
        self.MainMenuTitle.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">Main Menu</p></body></html>", None))
        self.logo.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">STATION</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">JEWELLERS </span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.LogOutButton.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "Logout", None))
        self.Changepassword.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "CHANGE PASSWORD", None))
        self.Staff.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "STAFF", None))
        self.Customer.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "CUSTOMERS", None))
        self.Repair.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "REPAIR", None))
        self.sale.setText(_translate("MainMenu", "SALE", None))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Login = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Login()
    ui.setupUi(Login)
    Login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is the random "a" I see in the middle of the code?

Comment: @EliasBenevedes sorry left over from when I cleaned up the badly formatted code

Comment: I cleaned up formatting in your question but you seem to be missing the class name and first method name so I just put `Something` please edit your question to fix that as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify `run_mainmenu` on `Something` and do the same you do when you initialize the `Login` window at the start of the app.

```
def run_mainmenu(self):
    Login.close()
    self.ui_mainmenu= Ui_MainMenu()
    self.mainmenu = QWidget() #or QDialog?
    self.ui_mainmenu.setupUi(self.mainmenu)
    self.mainmenu.show()
```

Another approach is to create a new class like `MainMenu` and subclass both of `Ui_MainMenu` and `QWidget` (yes use multi-inheritance!) and do something like this in your class constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.setupUi(self)
```

Then you just need to modify your function a little:

```
def run_mainmenu(self):
    Login.close()
    self.ui_mainmenu= MainMenu()
    self.mainmenu.show()
```

Just keep in mind that the Ui class generated by Qt is an utility class that initialize your ui, it also serves as a container for the widgets of the ui.
I prefer the first way I proposed you because this way you keep the generated code isolated. Both approach are very common, use the one you feel more comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

You derive `Ui_MainMenu` from `object`, which is not a Qt widget so it does not have a `show()` method. Derive it from `QWidget` or `QDialog` or such.

Comment: is there anyway of showing the window by deriving it from object? is there any other methods?

Comment: @Thaz why do you think you need to do that, what is issue with using qwidget etc?

Comment: @Thaz Looks like @xndrme sort of does this, although not quite: `mainmenu` is now a `QWidget` or `QDialog` (which is basically what I was saying but not via derivation) and it gets initialized from the `UI_MainMenu` instance. I +1'd his answer.